# Django celery beat doesn't see periodic task on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, celery, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, celerybeat

I have configured celery worker and celery beat on EB. There are no errors in logs during deploy and celery worker works fine, but doesn't see periodic tasks. On local machine everything works smoothly.

Here is my config file for the celery

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash

      # Create required directories
      sudo mkdir -p /var/log/celery/
      sudo mkdir -p /var/run/celery/

      # Create group called 'celery'
      sudo groupadd -f celery
      # add the user 'celery' if it doesn't exist and add it to the group with same name
      id -u celery &>/dev/null || sudo useradd -g celery celery
      # add permissions to the celery user for r+w to the folders just created
      sudo chown -R celery:celery /var/log/celery/
      sudo chmod -R 777 /var/log/celery/
      sudo chown -R celery:celery /var/run/celery/
      sudo chmod -R 777 /var/run/celery/

      # Get django environment variables
      celeryenv=`cat /opt/python/current/env | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/%/%%/g' | sed 's/export //g' | sed 's/$PATH/%(ENV_PATH)s/g' | sed 's/$PYTHONPATH//g' | sed 's/$LD_LIBRARY_PATH//g'`
      celeryenv=${celeryenv%?}

      # Create CELERY configuration script
      celeryconf="[program:celeryd]
      directory=/opt/python/current/app
      ; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
      command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery worker -A config.celery:app --loglevel=INFO --logfile="/var/log/celery/celery_worker.log" --pidfile="/var/run/celery/celery_worker_pid.pid"

      user=celery
      numprocs=1
      stdout_logfile=/var/log/std_celery_worker.log
      stderr_logfile=/var/log/std_celery_worker_errors.log
      autostart=true
      autorestart=true
      startsecs=10
      startretries=10

      ; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
      ; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
      stopwaitsecs = 60

      ; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
      ; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
      ; taking care of its children as well.
      killasgroup=true

      ; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
      ; so it starts first
      priority=998

      environment=$celeryenv"


      # Create CELERY BEAT configuraiton script
      celerybeatconf="[program:celerybeat]
      directory=/opt/python/current/app
      ; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
      command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery beat -A config.celery:app --loglevel=INFO --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler --logfile="/var/log/celery/celery_beat.log" --pidfile="/var/run/celery/celery_beat_pid.pid"

      user=celery
      numprocs=1
      stdout_logfile=/var/log/std_celery_beat.log
      stderr_logfile=/var/log/std_celery_beat_errors.log
      autostart=true
      autorestart=true
      startsecs=10
      startretries=10

      ; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
      ; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
      stopwaitsecs = 60

      ; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
      ; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
      ; taking care of its children as well.
      killasgroup=true

      ; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
      ; so it starts first
      priority=999

      environment=$celeryenv"

      # Create the celery supervisord conf script
      echo "$celeryconf" | tee /opt/python/etc/celery.conf
      echo "$celerybeatconf" | tee /opt/python/etc/celerybeat.conf

      # Add configuration script to supervisord conf (if not there already)
      if ! grep -Fxq "[include]" /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
        then
          echo "[include]" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
          echo "files: uwsgi.conf celery.conf celerybeat.conf" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
      fi

      # Enable supervisor to listen for HTTP/XML-RPC requests.
      # supervisorctl will use XML-RPC to communicate with supervisord over port 9001.
      # Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/911994/supervisorctl-3-3-1-http-localhost9001-refused-connection
      if ! grep -Fxq "[inet_http_server]" /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
        then
          echo "[inet_http_server]" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
          echo "port = 127.0.0.1:9001" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
      fi

      # Reread the supervisord config
      supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf reread

      # Update supervisord in cache without restarting all services
      supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf update

      # Start/Restart celeryd through supervisord
      supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart celeryd
      supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart celerybeat

commands:
  01_kill_other_beats:
    command: "ps auxww | grep 'celery beat' | awk '{print $2}' | sudo xargs kill -9 || true"
    ignoreErrors: true
  02_restart_beat:
    command: "supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart celerybeat"
    leader_only: true
  03_upgrade_pip_global:
    command: "if test -e /usr/bin/pip; then sudo /usr/bin/pip install --upgrade pip; fi"
  04_upgrade_pip_global:
    command: "if test -e /usr/local/bin/pip; then sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install --upgrade pip; fi"
  05_upgrade_pip_for_venv:
    command: "if test -e /opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip; then sudo /opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip; fi"
```

Can somebody say where is the error?

I start periodic task like this:

```
@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    pass
```

**Update:**
supervisord logs

```
2018-07-10 12:56:18,683 INFO stopped: celerybeat (terminated by SIGTERM)
2018-07-10 12:56:18,691 INFO spawned: 'celerybeat' with pid 1626
2018-07-10 12:56:19,181 INFO stopped: celerybeat (terminated by SIGTERM)
2018-07-10 12:56:20,187 INFO spawned: 'celerybeat' with pid 1631
2018-07-10 12:56:30,200 INFO success: celerybeat entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 10 seconds (startsecs)
2018-07-10 12:56:30,466 INFO stopped: celeryd (terminated by SIGTERM)
2018-07-10 12:56:31,472 INFO spawned: 'celeryd' with pid 1638
2018-07-10 12:56:41,486 INFO success: celeryd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 10 seconds (startsecs)
2018-07-10 13:28:32,572 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2018-07-10 13:28:32,573 WARN No file matches via include "/opt/python/etc/uwsgi.conf"
2018-07-10 13:28:32,573 WARN Included extra file "/opt/python/etc/celery.conf" during parsing
2018-07-10 13:28:32,573 WARN Included extra file "/opt/python/etc/celerybeat.conf" during parsing
2018-07-10 13:28:32,591 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2018-07-10 13:28:32,591 CRIT Server 'inet_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
```

Comment: First restart all celery tasks as you are using supervisor `sudo supervisorctl restart all` And then check.  Generally periodic tasks are getting used using decorator. `@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='*/30')), name="nameoftask", ignore_result=True)`

Comment: `sudo: supervisorctl: command not found`, without sudo `http://localhost:9001 refused connection`. On my local machine everyting works fine and I see periodic tasks on admin page. On EB there is no info about periodic task in admin page.

Comment: in your case use this command to restart all again, `supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart all`

Comment: `error: <class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 13] Permission denied: file: /usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py line: 228`

Comment: Which celery version you are using?

Comment: I use celery 4.2 with django 1.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the issue were imports when tried to set periodic tasks:

**celery.py**

```
@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    from my_app.tasks.task1 import some_task
    sender.some_task(
        60.0, some_task.s(), name='call every 60 seconds'
    )
```

The solution is to use task inside the celery app:

**celery.py**

```
@app.task
def temp_task():
    from my_app.tasks.task1 import some_task
    some_task()
```

so set periodic tasks will look like this

```
@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    from my_app.tasks.task1 import some_task
    sender.some_task(
        60.0, temp_task.s(), name='call every 60 seconds'
    )
```

It was difficult to get the source of the issue as there were no error logs and regular logs were empty as indeed celery was not started.